# Limit of $\frac{1-2+\cdots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{ (n^2+1)}+ \sqrt{ (n^2-1)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Here is the limit to be calculated :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-2+\cdots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{ (n^2+1)}+ \sqrt{ (n^2-1)}}$$

The question provides no other information.

**Doubts**

1. What is the domain of the function?
2. If the domain is $Z^+$, does limit exists for any $n\to integer$(since function wouldn't be defined in the neighborhood) and what about ${n\to\infty}$, how to interpret it ?

**My Try** : $$\frac{1-2+\cdots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{ (n^2+1)}+ \sqrt{ (n^2-1)}}=\frac{-n}{\sqrt{ (n^2+1)}+ \sqrt{ (n^2-1)}}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{ (1+1/n^2)}+ \sqrt{ (1-1/n^2)}}$$
hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-2+\cdots+(2n-1)-2n}{\sqrt{ (n^2+1)}+ \sqrt{ (n^2-1)}}= -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: the domain appears to be $|n|\geq1$ and the limit appears to be correct

Comment: Why $|n|\ge1$ and not $n\ge1$? What about $lim_{n\to5}$?Does it exist?  and Reading the definition of limit at infinity from here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity,
I think the limit above won't make sense. @DavidQuinn

Comment: The limit of a sequence, such as that given above,  (note the above is not a function of real $n$) is the unique value (if it exists) to which the sequence becomes arbitrarily close eventually.  You need not even say $n \to \infty$, the limit needs it.  Hence it also does not make sense in talking about $n \to 5$.

Comment: It could be a function from $Z^+\to R$ ?. @Macavity
EDIT : Okay. Thanks. That will do.

Comment: Just to clarify, $f: Z^+\mapsto \mathbb R$ defines a real sequence.

Answer (score 1):

1. “$1-2+\cdots+(2n-1)-2n$” only makes sense if $n$ is assumed to be a natural number. So the domain is most certainly $-$ using your notation $-$ $\mathbf{Z}^+$.
2. The limit of a sequence (which is a function from $\mathbf{Z}^+$ to $\mathbf{R}$) is defined as follows: A sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$ if for every $\varepsilon\gt0$ there is an $N\in\mathbf{Z}^+$ such that, for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}^+$, $$n\gt N\implies|a_n-\ell|\lt\varepsilon.$$ We then write $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\ell$, and we can say that the sequence $(a_n)$ has $\ell$ as a limit.

Comment: I would add that it does not make sense to say $n\to integer$, as OP suggests.